# How do we get a wave pulse and wave packet/train?

Tags: waves, everyday-life

Ok,

> *If a disturbance is localized to a small part of the space for a certain time we get a wave pulse and if the source is active for time greater than to complete a single pulse we get a wave packet.*
>
> H.C.Verma, Concept of physics, Part I.

However I don't understand what the author means by source, I mean what kind of mechanism induces a wave pulse?
Also if I consider the example of holding a string attached to a rigid support I can only visualize of making a sine or k*sine wave but not something like where there is nothing along negative $x$-axis which looks to me more like $|\sin x|$:

[image: A simple Wave Train/Packet]

To sum it up, I know what a wave pulse is, but I did like how could I produce one  practically? (Could I say ideally?)

Comment: Think of a "wave pulse" as a single (or even half) cycle of a sine wave.  To get a "wave train" you need the source to continue producing a positive, then negative pressure (sound pressure, or electric voltage, or whatever).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft , well I can think of half wave but not of how I can produce it?? Maybe the title is misleading?? or could you explain it more explicitly maybe I don't completely get what you're saying